# Select or unselect checkboxlist item using jquery on checkboxlist change

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist, selectlistitem

I have an Asp.net checkboxlist control (id:MyChklst) on my page and on selection change i am calling Jquery function.

But the problem is I want to uncheck or change the color f the item the item based on some validation in on-change function.

the below is the code i am using

Jquery Function :

```
        $('#MyChklst').on('click', ':checkbox', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 alert($(this).val());  // Working
                // alert($(this).text());  Not Working
                //$(this).css("background-color");  Not Working
                //$(this).attr('checked','false'); Not Working
            }
        });
```

Please help me out and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try that :

- make sure you are using clientID of the control, assuning that "MyChklst" is the control id :

> ```
> <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="MyChklst">
> ```

- Target the label next to the checkbox, Firefox/Chrome > Inspect to see how asp.net renders the final HTML.
- use [prop] : http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     $('#<%=MyChklst.ClientID %>').on('click', ':checkbox', function () {
>         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
>             alert($(this).val());  
>             alert($(this).next('label').text()); 
>             $(this).next('label').css("background-color","yellow"); 
>             $(this).prop('checked',false); 
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```